# Shliah Tzibbur's Repetition of Lines of Kedushah

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, chabad, kedusha-prayer

In kedushah, in hazarat ha-shatz, when the congregation has finished saying 'Kadosh kadosh kadosh...' and it's time for the shliah tzibbur to repeat the line out loud, it seems like the practice is for him to begin one word in. I.e., he must have said the first 'kadosh' silently already. Why is this?

Comment: I have not noticed this practice. Where have you seen it?

Comment: At various ashkenazic and hasidic minyanim on shabbat and yom tov. I think it seems to me that I notice it most of the time, most places.

Comment: You may just not be hearing it. As a teenager, I was corrected for not reciting the entire line out loud.

Comment: This is the custom in _Chabad_ synagogues in my experience. I've never seen it elsewhere that I recall (except in some specific instances, e.g. "_Keser_" on _Rosh Hashana_ and _Yom Kipur_).

Comment: Okay. Yes, actually it was at a Chabad shul recently that I heard it and was wondering about it. Maybe I'm mistaken about having heard it elsewhere. I'd still be interested to know rationale for it within chabad.

Comment: Could it be that the Chazzan is reciting the first word with the Tzibbur (so you don't hear it, whether he says it aloud or silently), and then waiting for the Tzibbur to quiet down so he can continue and be heard? Some (in my experience, many in Chabad) do this with Modim.

Comment: I don't think so, Seth. It seems like something done intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt once (sorry, no sources) that the Kedushah is responsive - Shatz and Kahal, but the Shatz is himself part of the Kahal, so in order not to separate himself from the Kahal he starts with them and prolongs the first word until they have quietened down. This is particularly important with Shema in Musaf. Alternatively the Shatz can say the response together with the Kahal and then carry straight on with the next section.